# Combining two linear regression model into a single linear model using covariates

Tags: regression, linear, mathematical-statistics

Let's say we have two very similar models:

$Y_{i}$ = 
$\beta_{0}+$
$\beta_{1}X_{1,i}
+\beta_{2}X_{2,i}+e_{i}$

and

$Y_{i}$ =
$\alpha_{0}$ +
$\alpha_{1}X_{1,i}
+\alpha_{2}X_{2,i}+e_{i}$

Let's say the first model is for men, and the second for women.

Mathematically, how do I combine the two linear regression models together? Do I multiply or add?

Additional information: The data sets are derived from Hamermesh & Biddle's (1994) paper of "Beauty and the labor market". And we divide the dummary variables into

$X_{1,i} = {above average looking}$

$X_{2,i} = {below average looking}$

$X_{3,i} = {female}$

Comment: What's the practicality of this? Wouldn't this be a LMM or hierarchical linear model?

Comment: How informative do you want the men data to be for the women model and vice versa? Not at all? Completely? Have the model learn it?

Comment: @Jon I am trying to write the model in a Matrix form so I can find the observations given in a table I have.

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat Just very general, and it doesn't need to be very informative.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a [fully interacted model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33692/joint-model-with-interaction-terms-vs-separate-regressions-for-a-group-comparis).

In which case, you interact all the terms with the dummy variable:

$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{1,i} + \beta_2 X_{2,i} + \beta_3 X_{3,i} + \beta_4 (X_{1,i}*X_{3,i}) + \beta_5 (X_{2,i}*X_{3,i}) + \epsilon_i$

$\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are the effects of $X_1$ and $X_2$ when $X_{3,i} = 0$

$\beta_1 + \beta_4$ is the effect of $X_1$ when $X_{3,i} = 1$

$\beta_2 + \beta_5$ is the effect of $X_2$ when $X_{3,i} = 1$

Comment: @pagma thanks! Could you explain me more how you derived that model? How did you set it up to end up with that?

Comment: For $X_3 = 0$, $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{1,i} + \beta_1 X_{2,i}$. For $X_3 = 1$, $Y_i = (\beta_0 * \beta_3) + (\beta_1 + \beta_4) * X_{1,i} + (\beta_2 + \beta_5) * X_{2,i}$. So in this case, $a_0 = (\beta_0 * \beta_3)$, $a_1 X_{1,i} = (\beta_1 + \beta_4) * X_{1,i}$, and $a_2 X_{2,i} = (\beta_2 + \beta_5) * X_{2,i}$.

Comment: @paqma Hey again! What does is "the effect of" mean? (referring back to your first post)

Comment: The unique variation of X associated with $Y$ (net of other variables). Standard interpretation of regression coefficients. How much of an increase in $Y$ is associated with a unit increase in $X$.